# How to load user control in page with specification?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0, web-user-controls

I have a user control where I taken two tables, now I want to add this user control to a aspx page. But there is a condition that I have to show only one table.
I am using `LoadControl("UC page url")` for loading.
Please help me to do this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Load user control by creating it's object in aspx page. Then you can check your condition by accessing the properties of the user control and implement the logic.